Error exporting GEE project
How can I export this project. I get this error:

Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type.
Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection.
(Error code: 3)

This is my code:
Map.addLayer(K7)
Map.centerObject(K7,10)

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')

var L8K7 = L8.filterBounds(K7);

var L8tanggal = L8K7.filterDate('2022-01-1','2022-12-31')
              
var medianL8 = L8.median();

var masking = function(img){
  var cloudshadowBitmask = (1<<4)
  var cloudshadowmask = (1<<3)
  var qa = img.select('QA_PIXEL')
  var maskshadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudshadowBitmask).eq(0)
  var maskcloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudshadowmask).eq(0)
  var mask = maskshadow.and(maskcloud)
  return img.updateMask(mask)
};


var L8clear = L8tanggal.sort('CLOUD_COVER_LAND')
                    .map(masking)
                    .median();

var L8potong = L8clear.clip(K7)

var scale = function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
};

var L8scale = scale(L8potong);

Map.addLayer(L8scale);

Map.addLayer(L8scale, imageVisParam, 'K7 True Color');

Map.centerObject(K7,10);


var nir = L8scale.select('SR_B5');
var red = L8scale.select('SR_B4');

var NDVI = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

var ndviSJ = NDVI.gt(-1).and(NDVI.lte(0.2)).selfMask()
var ndviJ = NDVI.gt(0.2).and(NDVI.lte(0.4)).selfMask()
var ndviS = NDVI.gt(0.4).and(NDVI.lte(0.6)).selfMask()
var ndviL = NDVI.gt(0.6).and(NDVI.lte(0.8)).selfMask()
var ndviSL = NDVI.gt(0.8).and(NDVI.lte(1)).selfMask()

Map.addLayer(ndviSJ,imageVisParam2,'sangat jarang')
Map.addLayer(ndviJ,imageVisParam3,'jarang')
Map.addLayer(ndviS,imageVisParam4,'sedang')
Map.addLayer(ndviL,imageVisParam5,'lebat')
Map.addLayer(ndviSL,imageVisParam6,'sangat lebat')

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L8,
  description: 'L8_NDVI',
  folder: 'GEE',
  scale: 30,
  region: K7,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  });

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9cad42c816046e606a0798322370173

The error occurs because the Export.image.toDrive() function expects an Image, but you are passing an ImageCollection (L8). To fix the error, you need to export a single image (e.g., L8clear or L8scale) instead of the whole collection (L8).
updated script to resolve the issue:
// Fix the Export statement by using L8scale (a single image) instead of the image collection (L8)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L8scale,  // Export the L8scale image, not the collection
  description: 'L8_NDVI',
  folder: 'GEE',
  scale: 30,
  region: K7,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5d5a194a1b8b30e34cabd69ce7082bc
